# How do I write a RE to match part of string

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a string: `Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 7)`

How can I match the part of string which is: `0, 0, 0, 7`?

Comment: Can you tell us if the "enter code here" is a part you want to match or a part you don't want to match. The font change is confusing.

Comment: "enter code here" is not a part of my string,Sorry about  that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure why you need this, but here is one way to get it done:

```
>>> import re
>>> e = r'(\d+,?)+'
>>> re.findall(e, 'Array(0, 0, 0, 7)')
['0,', '0,', '0,', '7']
```